# My Ubuntu 17.10 has stopped booting

Tags: boot, 17.10

When I turned on my machine today my Ubuntu 17.10 first off refused to log me in, returning to the log in prompt after, correct, entry of my password. I rebooted and now it gets stuck part way, the screen is black but *very* briefly flashes some white text repeatedly, which I am unable to read. There was an update last night, I am wondering if that broke something.

Comment: Ah - autoupdate?  Can you run through the procedures of [https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, some playing around after reading the stuff Charles pointed to and I went into the advanced menu and found 4 versions of the linux kernel listed
4.13.0-16
4.13.0-19
4.13.0-21
4.13.0-25

Using the latest 4.13.0-25 the system boots fine. I checked my GRUB configuration and the default "Ubuntu 17.10" option still pointed to "-19"! So there have been two updates and GRUB hasn't been updated for either. Anyway, this has fixed my problem now, thanks Charles for pointing me in the right direction.

I do wonder if this is a general problem, or if it is related to my use of "Grub Customizer". Either way it might help someone else who is stuck.

Comment: This looks like some additional information based on comments. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/994389/edit) your question and add this information in the question. Have you tried `sudo update grub`?

Comment: ~$ sudo update grub
[sudo] password: 
sudo: update: command not found